# Plupload browse button doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, plupload

I'm trying to make plupload running in IE9.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="uploader">
    <a id="browse" href="javascript:;">Browse...</a>
    <a id="upload" href="javascript:;">Upload...</a>
</div>
```

And js file:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes: 'html, flash, silverlight, html4',
    container: 'uploader',
    flash_swf_url: './Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url: './Moxie.xap',
    browser_button: 'browse',
    url: 'upload.php'
})
uploader.init();
```

The moxie is working correctly - it adds `div class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-flash"` element, but it doesn't work from start. 
The strange thing happends. It starts working when I click on that element in the developer tools DOM tree.

What could be a problem here ?

**EDIT:**

It starts working when I changed the configuration of the pluploader; to use silverlight instead of flash:

`runtimes: 'html5,silverligth,html4'`

Previous question still remains. It doesn't work for me with flash.

Comment: `runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution: 
Here is a piece of my PlUpload configuration:

```
runtimes: 'html5,silverlight,html4', //enable silverlight runtime (instead of flash)
container: NAME_OF_CONTAINER_ELEMENT,
silverlight_xap_url: PATH_TO_MOXIE //available in plupload package
```